# Make GlassFish v4 App on CloudBess

Tags: glassfish, java-7, cloudbees, glassfish-4

After some research I found CloudBess a really cool free Java Hosting server.

The problem is when I'm creating APP it takes many many time (I'm still waiting...) and just don't happen nothing

Like this image [image: waiting time!]

If anyone knows other free GlassFish server please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to report this issue to Web Development team, I am able to reproduce it on my instance. We will fix it as soon as possible.

Anyway, best way to deploy a Glassfish application on CloudBees platform is always through the [CloudBees SDK](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK) since it is the only tool you can use to manage all the features on the runtime environment.

- [Glassfish Web profile docs](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Glassfish4)
- [Glassfish Full profile docs](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Glassfish+4+Full+Platform)

To deploy your app is pretty straight forward. For example, for **Glassfish 4 web profile**, you just need to run this command with the CloudBees SDK.

```
bees app:deploy -t glassfish4 -a my-app path/to/my/app.war
```

On the other hand, for the **full profile**, it is:

```
bees app:deploy -a myapp -t glassfish4-full path/to/my/app.war
```